# Open a single application on Raspberry Pi2

Tags: raspbian

I am using Raspberry Pi 2 and i want to open a single application on it that is i want to open just a pdf file in it and remove all the rest of thing from it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Please explain what you want to do, but do it well, (or at least better).

Comment: actually i just want to build a pi which can only read pdf file nothing else.Even i want to remove all the GUI .So that it can read only PDF files nothing else!!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you're aiming for using [Minimal Kiosk Browser](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=40860).

From its [documentation](http://steinerdatenbank.de/software/kweb_manual.pdf):

> Kweb can be used
>
> 1. as a browser for your desktop
> 2. to replace your desktop completely
> 3. as front end for embedded applications (kiosk mode)
>
> ...
>
> [See section: PDF Support]
>
> Kweb supports three different PDF programs: mupdf, xpdf and evince.
>   Kwebhelper will use evince, if it is installed, then it will look for
>   xpdf and use mupdf as last resort. You can select the PDF program you
>   want to use on the settings page.